# Font Awesome and Sass fail on my project

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass, font-awesome

I am working on Windows and I am using bower, this is my app.sass:

```
$fa-font-path: "/lib/font-awesome/fonts"
@import 'lib/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome'
```

I have the same project on Linux and runs well, but on Windows fails, this  is bug:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1) Do not use @import css (it limits the ability of the browser parallel load).

Recommendations

```
<link href='my css' rel='stylesheet'>
```

2) edit

```
@import 'lib/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome'
```

to

```
@import '/lib/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome'
```

Done